# Postman - Highlighting particular cells

Tags: postman

Is it possible to highlight or add background color to particular cells in Postman like we do it in Excel ?

For e.g: In below image, if I want to highlight Personal information and Address details row, then can I do that in Postman ?

[image]

Comment: In short, no.  If it is something that you would like to see in the product, you could submit a feature request so that the team is aware.